# Mongodb: Group by element and show the sub-document count based on condition and sort the document by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've collections of documents as like as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d4410544c96d6f6578f893"),
    "executionProject" : "Project1",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS",
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T08:40:47.049Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T08:40:37.621Z"),
    "runStatus" : "PASS",
    "__v" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d44eb4c0422e7b8bffe76b"),
    "executionProject" : "Project1",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS",
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:39:13.528Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:39:00.406Z"),
    "runStatus" : "PASS",
    "__v" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d44f0bc0422e7b8bffe76f"),
    "executionProject" : "Project1",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "FAIL",
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:46:31.108Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:40:27.377Z"),
    "runStatus" : "PASS",
    "__v" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d463d0c0422e7b8bffe789"),
    "executionProject" : "Project2",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "FAIL"
        },
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS"
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:52.537Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:04.539Z"),
    "runStatus" : "FAIL",
    "__v" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d464ebc0422e7b8bffe7c2"),
    "executionProject" : "Project3",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "FAIL"
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:18:41.460Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:13:47.268Z"),
    "runStatus" : "FAIL",
    "__v" : 10
}
```

And I'm expecting output as follows:

```
[
    {
        "executionProject": "Project1",
        "suite-pass": 0,
        "suite-fail": 1,
        "runEndTime": ISODate("2015-08-19T09:46:31.108Z")
    },
    {
        "executionProject": "Project2",
        "suite-pass": 1,
        "suite-fail": 1,
        "runEndTime": ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:52.537Z")
    },
    {
        "executionProject": "Project3",
        "suite-pass": 0,
        "suite-fail": 1,
        "runEndTime": ISODate("2015-08-19T11:18:41.460Z")
    },
]
```

I want to group by project and order by runEndTime and show the pass and fail counts of suiteList.

I know how to get the suite pass and fail counts of all runs, but not sure how can I group and order. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation framework with the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator seems to be what you are after:

```js
  Model.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$suiteList" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$executionProject",
      "suite-pass": { 
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$suiteList.suiteStatus", "PASS" ] },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "suite-fail": { 
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$suiteList.suiteStatus", "FAIL" ] },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "runEndTime": { "$max": "$runEndTime" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "runEndTime": 1 }}
  ],function(err,result) {

  });
```

This conditionally tests the values for either "PASS" or "FAIL" and returns these to the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator under [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). In the same way you take the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) value for the relevant date per grouped documents.

The final thing is just to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by that date

---

If the "suiteList" in fact will only ever ccontain one "PASS" and one "FAIL" at maximum, then you can likely get away without even using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the array:

```js
  Model.aggregate(
    [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$executionProject",
        "suite-pass": {
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$anyElementTrue": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$suiteList",
                  "as": "suite",
                  "in": {
                    "$eq": [ "$$suite.suiteStatus", "PASS" ]
                  }
                }
              }},
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "suite-fail": {
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$anyElementTrue": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$suiteList",
                  "as": "suite",
                  "in": {
                    "$eq": [ "$$suite.suiteStatus", "FAIL" ]
                  }
                }
              }},
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "runEndTime": { "$max": "$runEndTime" }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "runEndTime": 1 }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
  )
```

The [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$anyElementTrue`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) in there can similarly test the the conditions in the array matched where they should be counted. So as long as the "number of matches" per document does not matter, then this is fine.

On your data here that does meet those conditions, then both produce the same result:

```js
{
    "_id" : "Project1",
    "suite-pass" : 2,
    "suite-fail" : 1,
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:46:31.108Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "Project2",
    "suite-pass" : 1,
    "suite-fail" : 1,
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:52.537Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "Project3",
    "suite-pass" : 0,
    "suite-fail" : 1,
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:18:41.460Z")
}
```

To get the "last" items then simply `$sort` first and replace the `$sum` accumlators with the [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) accumulator:

```js
  Model.aggregate(
    [
      { "$sort": { "runEndTime": 1 } },
      { "$group": {
      "_id": "$executionProject",
        "suite-pass": {
          "$last": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$anyElementTrue": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$suiteList",
                  "as": "suite",
                  "in": {
                    "$eq": [ "$$suite.suiteStatus", "PASS" ]
                  }
                }
              }},
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "suite-fail": {
          "$last": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$anyElementTrue": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$suiteList",
                  "as": "suite",
                  "in": {
                    "$eq": [ "$$suite.suiteStatus", "FAIL" ]
                  }
                }
              }},
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "runEndTime": { "$last": "$runEndTime" }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "runEndTime": 1 } }
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
  );
```

Which produces:

```js
{
    "_id" : "Project1",
    "suite-pass" : 0,
    "suite-fail" : 1,
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:46:31.108Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "Project2",
    "suite-pass" : 1,
    "suite-fail" : 1,
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:52.537Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "Project3",
    "suite-pass" : 0,
    "suite-fail" : 1,
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:18:41.460Z")
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Do you mind answer my question? How I'm getting only the distinct value of executionProject? Is that group does that magic?

Comment: @Vimal The `$group` has an `_id` which is the "grouping key" for it's aggregation. Yes it is meant to return only distinct values of the fields it is grouping on.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong. I was expecting the Project1's `suite-pass` count is 0 and `suite-fail` count is 1 since at the runEndTime `2015-08-19T09:40:27.377Z`, there is only one suite and that too failed. I don't want the number of all suites in every run of that project. Currently un-marking the answer, but soon will mark it again if we find any other better solution.

Comment: @Vimal Why would the counts be different to what the data you provide lists? Even a visual check with my eyes says the reported counts are correct.

Comment: Basically I would like to see the latest run count by project. I don't want to see the count of previous runs. The output of your query gives me the count of all runs.

Comment: @Vimal Sorry, so all you are really after is the "last date" for each project and return the "pass & fail" matches for that single item?

Comment: @Vimal Sorry was busy doing something else. To get your result the change is a simple swap of other accumulators for `$last`. See the example above

Comment: Awesome Blakes. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Blakes, just noticed that if I have more than one suite in array with the same status, I get the count as 1 instead of 2. Please refer my updated question.

Comment: @Vimal You only get to ask one question per question on stack overflow. Ask another question. I will not answer your new question on a question that was already answered.

Comment: I'm sorry Blakes, I can answer this question in another thread. But I thought you might have misunderstood my question. I'll open a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @Vimal Well. What you have demonstrated exactly on two occasions now is removing your acceptance and expecting to hold someone ransom to run back and answer more questions for you. That sort of thing gets rememberred.

Comment: it makes sense. I marked this answer as accepted and opened a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197955/aggregate-with-count-of-sub-documents-matching-the-condition-and-grouping