# Aggregate with count of sub documents matching the condition and grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've collections of documents as like as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d4410544c96d6f6578f893"),
    "executionProject" : "Project1",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS"
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T08:40:47.049Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T08:40:37.621Z"),
    "runStatus" : "PASS",
    "__v" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d44eb4c0422e7b8bffe76b"),
    "executionProject" : "Project1",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS"
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:39:13.528Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:39:00.406Z"),
    "runStatus" : "PASS",
    "__v" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d44f0bc0422e7b8bffe76f"),
    "executionProject" : "Project1",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "FAIL"
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:46:31.108Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:40:27.377Z"),
    "runStatus" : "PASS",
    "__v" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d463d0c0422e7b8bffe789"),
    "executionProject" : "Project2",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS"
        },
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS"
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:52.537Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:04.539Z"),
    "runStatus" : "FAIL",
    "__v" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d464ebc0422e7b8bffe7c2"),
    "executionProject" : "Project3",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteStatus" : "FAIL"
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:18:41.460Z"),
    "runStartTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:13:47.268Z"),
    "runStatus" : "FAIL",
    "__v" : 10
}
```

And I'm expecting output as follows:

```
[
    {
        "executionProject": "Project1",
        "suite-pass": 0,
        "suite-fail": 1,
        "runEndTime": ISODate("2015-08-19T09:46:31.108Z")
    },
    {
        "executionProject": "Project2",
        "suite-pass": 2,
        "suite-fail": 0,
        "runEndTime": ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:52.537Z")
    },
    {
        "executionProject": "Project3",
        "suite-pass": 0,
        "suite-fail": 1,
        "runEndTime": ISODate("2015-08-19T11:18:41.460Z")
    },
]
```

I want to group by project and order by runEndTime and show the pass and fail counts of suiteList.

I tried this as suggested by Blakes in [Mongodb: Group by element and show the sub-document count based on condition and sort the document by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175075/mongodb-group-by-element-and-show-the-sub-document-count-based-on-condition-and):

```
db.testruns.aggregate([
      { "$sort": { "runEndTime": 1 } },
      { "$group": {
      "_id": "$executionProject",
        "suite-pass": {
          "$last": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$anyElementTrue": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$suiteList",
                  "as": "suite",
                  "in": {
                    "$eq": [ "$$suite.suiteStatus", "PASS" ]
                  }
                }
              }},
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "suite-fail": {
          "$last": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$anyElementTrue": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$suiteList",
                  "as": "suite",
                  "in": {
                    "$eq": [ "$$suite.suiteStatus", "FAIL" ]
                  }
                }
              }},
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "runEndTime": { "$last": "$runEndTime" }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "runEndTime": 1 } }
    ]);
```

I was expecting the `suite-pass` count for `Project2` as 2 since there are 2 elements in suiteList, but it returns 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have read the answer properly, as there already was another alternate listing and explanation of why the expected result you want from the one you used would be different.

Instead you want this one, which respects the possible multiple "PASS" or "FAIL":

```js
  Model.aggregate(
    [
      { "$sort": { "executionProject": 1, "runEndTime": 1 } },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$executionProject",
        "suiteList": { "$last": "$suiteList" },
        "runEndTime": { "$last": "$runEndTime" }
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$suiteList" },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "suite-pass": { 
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$suiteList.suiteStatus", "PASS" ] },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "suite-fail": { 
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$suiteList.suiteStatus", "FAIL" ] },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "runEndTime": {"$first": "$runEndTime"}
      }},
      { "$sort": { "runEndTime": 1 }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
  );
```

Which is sort of a "combination" of approaches. The first is to get the "last" by runTime as you were expecting. The next is to break down the array and this time actually "sum up" the possible occurances of pass or fail, rather than just record a `1` for either pass or fail in the array, the actual "pass" or "fail" are counted.

With results:

```js
{
        "_id" : "Project1",
        "suite-pass" : 0,
        "suite-fail" : 1,
        "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T09:46:31.108Z")
}
{
        "_id" : "Project2",
        "suite-pass" : 2,
        "suite-fail" : 0,
        "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:09:52.537Z")
}
{
        "_id" : "Project3",
        "suite-pass" : 0,
        "suite-fail" : 1,
        "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T11:18:41.460Z")
}
```

Comment: You are a genius man. I would like to offer you a beer if you are around here.

Answer (score 1):

Unwind `suiteList` and used `$sum` in `group` as below :

```
db.testruns.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$suiteList"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$executionProject",
        "suite-pass": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": ["$suiteList.suiteStatus", "PASS"]
                    },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "suite-fail": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": ["$suiteList.suiteStatus", "FAIL"]
                    },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "runEndTime": {
            "$last": "$runEndTime"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        "runEndTime": 1
    }
})
```

Comment: This returns the suite-pass count as 2 and suite-fail count as 1 for `Project1`. I was expecting the suite-pass count as 0 and suite-fail count as 1.

Comment: @Vimal You do realize this is a direct copy paste from the answer I gave you originally before you made it clear you wanted the "last" and not the "sum". Just so you know what you are rewarding.